# Coding standards for MVC - Are they any official ones?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can anyone tell me if there are any coding standards for MVC things like Controller Names, View Names? I just started building a web site and I would like to do it the right way from the start.

Also looking for a really good example application that I could maybe learn from. I already saw Nerd Dinner. Is there some other sample applications that you could recommend me to look at?

Hope someone can tell me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Best Practices for ASP.NET MVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/09/17/second_2d00_post.aspx)

[ASP.NET MVC 3 Code Examples from MSDN](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/aspnetmvcsamples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5114)

Also, check out [PluralSight's free training](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the latest version of Visual Studio (even the express edition) it should help you by providing templates that use the conventional names.