# CodingStandard for ASP.NET 4 MVC webapps

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a piece of Software in ASP.NET. The project is a C# ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application.

The requirement for the piece of software is to use a Coding Standard. 
There is already a lot of generated code in the project, done by VisualStudio itself.
But what CodingStandard do they use? So I can use the same CodingStandard in my own code. It'll probably be documented in MSDN, but the only Coding Standard I found was the C# Coding Standard.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639389/coding-standards-for-mvc-are-they-any-official-ones

Comment: No, it's not. It's more something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx that I'm looking for. Real documentation. Not example things.